# Canvas to image drawing not successful

Tags: java, image, canvas, graphics, java-8

First code snippet is my main render method. I am creating buffer strategy, then getState().render(g) is passing Graphics object and it calls a bunch of g.drawImage() methods, after all that, saveImage() gets called and it produces completely black image (games screenshot expected). Second snippet is saving canvas to image.

```
private void render() {
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    if (State.getState() != null)
        State.getState().render(g); // this just calls g.drawImage many times

    saveImage(g);

    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

This is how I save it:

```
private void saveImage(Graphics g) {
    BufferedImage image = new  BufferedImage(getCanvas().getWidth(), getCanvas().getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
    display.getCanvas().paint(graphics);
    graphics.dispose();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("snapshot.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two entirely different `Graphics` objects involved, one acquired from a `BufferedImage` and one acquired from `BufferStrategy`. That doesn’t work well together. It’s also not clear why you are doing it that way. Apparently, your actual rendering routine is `State.getState().render(g)`, so you may call it with either `Graphics` object, depending on whether you want to render to a buffer for on-screen rendering or into the `BufferedImage` for saving. Don’t call `paint` on a `Canvas`…

Comment: @Holger This is a video game so it's rendering on screen, but I wanted to learn how to take a screenshot. I tried geting `Graphics`object from `Canvas` with no luck. What should I call on `Canvas` than? Thanks.

Comment: You should never mix up screen rendering routines and file I/O operations. Besides that, the structure should be simple, there has to be code in your application drawing into a `Graphics`. That code can be called either with a `Graphics` of a screen buffer or with a `Graphics` from a `BufferedImage` to produce the same graphic for different purposes. If done right, i.e. when not letting rendering routines modify shared state, you could even execute the code concurrently with the different `Graphics`, without slowing down the game.

Comment: Or you [take a true screenshot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture-java.awt.Rectangle-), which is not even related to `Graphics`. Or in other words, the standard graphic operations as exposed though `Graphics` are not capable of reading the screen buffers back.

Comment: @Holger `Robot` works! Thank you for help, you should post that as an answear for visability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not take a screenshots using ordinary operations on a `Graphics` object¹.

If your system supports it, you can use the AWT [`Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/awt/Robot.html) class, i.e. its method [`createScreenCapture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture-java.awt.Rectangle-) to create a screenshot.

For systems not supporting reading back screen data, the best option is to design the application so that the same rendering routines (operating on a `Graphics`) can be used in both contexts, when rendering in a screen buffer and when rendering in an off-screen image to be saved. This might not always reproduce the exact image, but is the best you can get on such systems.

---

¹ it would be possible through some tricks, e.g. implementing a custom `Composite`, recording the incoming data, but it would be much more complicated to implement than using `Robot` and undergo the same restrictions, i.e. it still wouldn’t work on all platforms.